# Sony Vaio Wireless Not Working 32 bit Windows 7 ultimate

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, drivers, 32-bit, sony-vaio

I have a Sony Vaio SVE15111ENB laptop which came with Windows 7 Home Basic 64 bit where Vaio Smart Network was installed initially. I replaced Home Basic Edition with Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit. But when trying to install Vaio Smart Network in 32 bit, it doesn't seem to work. I also installed Aethros wireless driver, but that is also not working. How can i make my wireless connection on my laptop work?

Answer (score 0):

You should download the drivers from the [official site](http://www.sony.co.in/support/product/sve15111en/download) since it's the most up-to-date and secure. Download all drivers and install them including: Applications and Utilities, BIOS, Drivers and Firmware.

**Or**

Since your laptop came with a Windows 7 Home Basic Edition *64 bit*, you should get the 64 bit version of Windows 7 Ultimate instead of *32 bit* version. If you bought Windows 7 Ultimate separately, it should come with a 64 bit version.

If this didn't help, please warm me. GL!

Comment: official site contains drivers for only 64 bit! not 32 bit

Comment: Sorry for late reply. The 64 bit drivers are there. At `Select operating system` select `Windows® Microsoft® Ultimate 7 32-bit` and you should get the 32- bit drivers and software.